# JavaScript good practice to run many function/object one by one until find result

Tags: javascript, promise, artificial-intelligence

What Would be the good practice to execute many JavaScript object one after another like a pipeline/chain. When Match found exit code and return result.

```js
        function a() {
            // found result 
            // if not found return false
            if (2===3){
                return 'result A';
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        function b() {
            // If a() False
            // True = Match Result
            if (true){
                return 'result B';
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        function c() {
            // if not found in b() find here
            if (true){
                return 'result C';
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        function aibot() {
            return a() || b() || c(); // Some more function
        }
        console.log(aibot());
```

js Promise Would be good solution?
Please Give some suggestion.

Comment: This is pretty broad as asked; there are any number of ways this could be handled.

Comment: They aren't asynchronous so a Promise doesn't really come into play here.  Just make an array of function references, iterate the array, and call the iterator (the function).  Do you **expect** any of those functions that you want to pipeline to ever be asynchronous?

Comment: the example you wrote is clear enough and in the same situation I would go for that. But as the top comment it all depends on how you want to handle

Comment: @zero298 Can you make an Example?

Comment: Please clarify the expectation first because that will affect the implementation.  Should this deal with asynchronous functions.

Comment: It will not be asynchronous functions.

Comment: I am using promise only to run `aibot()`.
var label = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve(aibot(feature));
        }).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take `some` and an array of functions, as well as a value as return value if a function returns a truthy value.

```js
function a() { return false; }
function b() { return 'result B'; }
function c() { return 'result C'; }

function aibot() {
    var value;
    [a, b, c].some(fn => value = fn());
    return value;
}

console.log(aibot());
```

Comment: That's really nice. I would be tempted to return `value || undefined`, but the OP isn't explicit about what the return value should be if no matches are found.

Comment: If No match return false

Comment: if your function return `false` by default, then just take it as above, otherwise return the result of `some` or `value`, like `return [a, b, c].some(fn => value = fn()) && value;`

Comment: @TylerRoper doesn't `some()` stop on the first true value?

Comment: @ShaponPal, for all calls the same, or different parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to return the first non-falsy-returning function, and then run it again to get it's result. Of course, you'd probably like to have a fallback in the event that all of your functions return falsy values.

```js
const a = () => false;
const b = () => false;
const c = () => "Hello world";

var aibot = [a, b, c].find(f => f()) || (() => false);
console.log(aibot());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think sometimes you are better off with a simple loop. This will only run until the first function that returns true and will return that value without having to call the function again. It will return `undefined` if no function returns a truthy value. You will need to consider if all non-truths values (like `0`) should be ignored:

```js
function a() { return false}
function b() {return 'result B'}
function c() { return 'result C'}

function takeFirst(arr){
    for (let f of arr) {
        let r = f()
        if (r) return r
    }
}

console.log(takeFirst([a, b, c]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findFirstMatchingResult(arr, val){
  for(let i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){
    const result = arr[i]();
    if(result === val){
      return true;
    }
   }

   return false;
}


// if you really want to make it generic, you could do the following:

function findFirstMatchingResult(arr, val){
  return function(...params){
    for(let i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){
      const result = arr[i].apply(null, params[i]);
      if(result === val){
        return true;
      }
     }

     return false; 
  }
}

findFirstMatchingResult([
 function(str){
   return str.length;
 }
])([
 'hello'
]);
```

The generic version(Functions can have arguments) is definitely a little cumbersome having to pass an array for each function, but it's a good starting point. It would also only would for primitives. As === will not work for array, objects, etc.